# AS400 YYYYMMDD - 1 month

Tags: ibm-midrange

We get data from one of our partners that is running an i5 AS/400 database.
Their date columns are all in YYYYMMDD format. In my query, I want to get only stuff added in the last month.

I know I can get the current_date and subtract 1 month, but it comes in date format.
So my choices are to either take the YYYYMMDD and convert it to date format, or take the current date and change it to YYYYMMDD format.

Since the AS/400 is missing out on the convert command that tsql has, I'm not sure which the best way to go is.

Comment: If you're willing to add another join... do they have a calendar file?  That'll also eliminate invalid dates from the results.  It'd be best, of course, if you could get the type in the database changed - if they're dealing with a `*CYMD` date, they have the necessary facilities to handle it in their RPG programs; disk space probably isn't really an issue any more.  Especially because it prevents invalid data.

Comment: It's probably the most poorly designed database I've come across. And it's basically impossible to get them to do anything to improve it. Even a unique identity column would be a huge improvement (versus the PK of CustomerName, LogNumber, and Date). I'm not totally sure that they've ever heard of the term Normalization. That being said, at least it's not in CYMD date format. That would probably be even worse. It's an integer field with YYYYMMDD format, unless something goes wrong in their system and a 0 gets inserted instead...

Comment: #smacks self#  Right, not in the actual RPG date format `*CYMD` (which is a 3-digit year with the 21st century denoted by '1').  I guess I've been dealing too much with other date stuff - the first two digits of a four-digit year are, of course, the century.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learned this trick from the [MIDRANGE-L list](http://archive.midrange.com/midrange-l/201110/msg00665.html).

```
YYYYMMDD <= DEC(REPLACE(CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - 1 MONTH, ISO), '-', ''), 8, 0)
```

Comment: That's a nice way to do it!  I keep forgetting that `CHAR` lets you specify the date format.

Comment: I can't take any credit for the answer. Birgitta Hauser of the MIDRANGE-L list sent me the solution when I was having similar problems. Thus the link for attribution.

Comment: dmc's solution does work, but this is pretty short and elegant. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to put the date you're seeking in YYYYMMDD format. That way you're letting the database do its job of comparing data against query specs.

Comment: This method can lead to problems. See the link in my solution. I had problems with a query that initially worked, then started to fail for some reason.

Comment: Ah, yes, the ill-formed date put in there by other ill-conceived processes. You've got a good solution. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're saying that the date column is actually eight-digit numeric field that happens to contain values that we interpret as dates.  I also assume you're running these queries directly against the i5 database.

You will want to convert a date into the YYYYMMDD numeric value, then query against the YYYYMMDD field.  Converting the YYYYMMDD value in the database to a date and comparing against that will require each value to be converted, which will eliminate the possibility of using an index over that column.  It also opens you up to problems due to invalid dates in the YYYYMMDD field.

Here's an example of converting a date calculation to an eight-digit number as YYYYMMDD:

```
select year(current_date - 1 month) * 10000 +
       month(current_date - 1 month) * 100 + 
       day(current_date - 1 month)           
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

You could use this in a query like this:

```
select *                              
from libname.tablename                    
where date_field >=                          
  year(current_date - 1 day) * 10000 +
  month(current_date - 1 day) * 100 + 
  day(current_date - 1 day)
```

An alternative is to use a tool like IDATE.  This makes conversions of numerics to dates much easier.  [Go to this link and search for IDATE](http://archive.midrange.com/rpg400-l/200704/msg00735.html) for more information about this option.

Comment: This does work, and I learned some useful stuff about handling dates, so awesome. IDate isn't an option, since I don't have any real access to the system except read only through a linked server.